# Multiple Manifest Files

Tags: android

I have a project in Eclipse and I have split my application into multiple packages namely Presentation logic and Business Logic.    The Business Logic package I set as a library and imported this into the 
presentation logic.    This all worked fine.

In the above I have a service and a receiver defined in the Presentation Manifest and I have now decided
that I want to move this business logic functionality to the Business Logic package.   This went well and I thought it was going to work but unfortunately not as expected.

If I move the Service and receiver information from the Presentation Manifest to the BusinessLogic Manifest then only the Presentation Logic APK file is loaded.   Whereas if I have these in the Presentation Logic manifest file, I see a message in the logs that states a dependency on BusinessLogic was detected and it starts to load the Business Logic APK file.

My first question is in this scenario, where should I place the serice and receiver manifest entry in the presentation logic manifest file or the business logic file.   Obviously when in the Presentation Logic manifest, I need to fully qualify the entries.

Now to my second question.

As I previously mentioned, when I use the Presentation Layer manifest file, the receiver is started.  I can check this by placing a breakpoint in the receiver OnCreate.   However the problem is that I do not see the Business Logic code shown in the debugger.

I think this issue is as a result of the first point but I am not clear what is happening.

As you can see I am a little confused in respect to the correct use of the manifest files when using libraries or multiple packages and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to split your app. Passing around information will become quite hard so just wondering: why will you do so?

Comment: Probably lack of experience in Android development.   My business logic is a service that keeps a local database up to date on regular intervals.    The presentation layer GUI basically presents the database info to the user.   I thought this was a good seperation to have the Service in the business logic.

Comment: Is it normal to only have one manifest file per a whole application when using Android?  If this is the case why do we need a manifest with libraries?    I really would appreciate your advice as I am confused with how best to structure an Android application in Eclipse.   thx

Comment: I have only worked with the android support libaries, in that case you only need one manifest. As far as I know you only ever have one manifest per app. Hope that helps

Comment: I really recommend you to read the fundamentals of android's system. You can't avoid to get your head around it to actually appreciate the platform :) I also can not imagine a situation with multiple manifest files. The manifest file is somewhat like an "XML intruction manual" for your app. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I previously mentioned, when I use the Presentation Layer manifest
>   file, the receiver is started. I can check this by placing a
>   breakpoint in the receiver OnCreate. However the problem is that I do
>   not see the Business Logic code shown in the debugger.

OK I admit I have to guess here but as I understood you have a Presentation and a Business App running. Since you're talking about 2 different APK.

Android is running on a unix based system and technically every app will be assigned with a new user in the operating system. By default only this user (read: app) has the rights to read and modify it's own files.
Though it is possible that different apps may share their data I'm doubting it's really necessary in your case.

I also don't see why you shouldn't use classes. E.g. a presentation class for styling your data which accesses methods provided by the BusinessLogic class. where the latter takes care of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I think the above answer is misleading while separate apps may spawn a new thread you have only one app. I know you can't dynamically change permissions, they must be set when the app is installed. To change permissions you must re-install the app(security issue). Also android is designed for personal devices so there is no such thing as user accounts, superuser, administrator as far as the system is concerned so this functionality (inherited from Linux) is assigned to vendors by use of a unique package name. If you download another app from the same vendor I guess they inherit privileges from the first app, strange but what ever. I think the solution is to have one manifest in the main activity with an include type statement like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx however I am not sure how to go about it. I would search XML documentation on how to do this. I hope I pointed you in the right direction, good luck.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

Lookie what I found. http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_include.asp  Maybe this will help.